# Adding Double Quotes to CSV Header in Azure Data Factory

Tags: csv, dataset, azure-data-factory

The headers in the CSV look something like this:
Name, Date, ID

I need the headers to be encapsulated by double quotation marks, something like this:
"Name", "Date", "ID"

Note: The data below the headers are correctly encapsulated by double quotation marks, only the headers are missing them.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a data flow activity and under sink settings, choose Quote All text.

Sink dataset settings

[image: Sink Setting]

Dataflow Sink Tab setting
[image: DataSet Sink]

After execution, my file looks like

[image: File content]

Comment: The box is greyed out, looks like it's already selected.

Comment: Ok , did you run it and check the output

Comment: Yes, the quotation marks are missing around the headers and null values.

Comment: Hello David, i have updated my answer with the settings that work for me. FYI, my sink dataset is of Delimited text type.